# don' allow user to open ASP.NET web application on multiple tabs

Tags: asp.net, web-applications

I'm pretty new to ASP.NET, can anyone please give me a hint in a way to forbid user to open the same WEB app in multiple tabs.

Comment: I am not sure there is an "offical" way to do this. However, I would advice to use cookie to store the number of times your webapp has been opened, and displaying a pretty message if it has been opened more than once. You could use database if you are not used to use cookies.

Comment: @Zeratops thank you for the idea, I've worked with cookies in php, I'm expecting it will be the same thing.